# AutoCAD CUIX: Swapping my LISP routine’s mapped drive URL link in my Macro with the Google Share Drive web based link of the same file

Tags: url, syntax, macros, load, autocad

My LISP routines are on the Google Share Drive at my work. I have buttons in my custom ribbon that calls my routines using a mapped drive letter URL link.

URL Link example in my custom Macro:
[image]

**Goal:**

Trying to share this with the other CAD users in the office.

**Problem:**

Various CAD Users have different mapped drive letters (Ex: H:\ or S:\ instead of G:).
Trying to avoid going around and manually changing the drive letter to match their mapping every time I updated the CUIX file (since path would be overwritten).
Would like to use the universal Google Share Drive web based link (by selecting the file and choose "get link" in Google Drive and copy the link).

**The Swap:**

Current URL Mapping in my Macro example (if image above not showing):

^C^C(load "G:\shardrive\CAD_Department\CAD_menu\LISP\My_routine.lsp");My_routine;

Example of swapping with the Google Share Drive link (not working):

^C^C(load "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BlU92IihdhhcnRlcl9mWxl/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-0VxGZXU_D8YjtjgjzQZnQ");My_routine;

Another method I tried
^C^C(command-s "_browser" "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BlU92IihdhhcnRlcl9mWxl/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-0VxGZXU_D8YjtjgjzQZnQ/");My_routine;

Anyone know the proper syntax for the macro?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a more configurable approach is needed, where the users can map the drives with whatever path they want (G:, S:\ or whatever). But they can still use the tools that are inside said drive.

To do this there are three things that would help:

1.) start using AutoCAD profiles. It's possible write a setup script to create the profile for the user. This profile would contain a support file path entry for the location of your LISP code. The path would vary depending on where the user has google drive mapped to.
2.) load all LISP from the profile when AutoCAD starts up, this can be done with the acaddoc.lsp file.
3.) remove all hard-coded load statements from the CUI buttons

Comment: Thank you for the great information. I will look into your solutions. I have had issues with the CUIX Macro on other commands as well.  Opening a folder through a button. This link shows my issues but their solutions still don't work for me... https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/topic/62049-open-specific-folder-in-explorer/ - I need to keep looking for answers on opening a folder from the Macro line only and not a separate LISP routine.

Comment: np. I've setup some solutions like you are asking for in the past. feel free to reach out to me at my gmail account if you need more help cadwiki.net@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue I mentioned in my comment above about opening a folder through the CUIX macro only (and not through a LISP routine), I found this possible solution:

```
^C^C(startapp "explorer" (vl-string-translate "/" (chr 92) "C:/TEMP"));
```

Credit to  **Paul_Gander** and his comments located here:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/open-a-folder-with-a-button/td-p/3010928

More testing needed but so far so good...

Thank you Paul!